# How can I hide numbers on x-axis and y -axis but keep grid of this graph?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am drawing graph of the function `y = x^4 - 5x^2 + 4`. Now I want to hide numbers on x-axis and y -axis but keep grid of this graph. How can I do it? My code is

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tabvar}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    [declare function={Y(\x)=\x^4 - 5 * \x^2 + 4;},
    axis lines = center,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
        domain=-2.5:2.5,
        ymin=-2.5,
        ymax=5.5,
        xmin=-2.5,
        xmax=2.5,
    samples=100,xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=1,unit vector ratio*=1 1 1,
    width=11cm,
    grid=major,
    grid style={gray!30}
    ]
       \addplot [black, thick] {Y(x)};
       %\addplot [black, mark=*,only marks,samples at={-1,1,-2,2}] {Y(x)};
       \node at (axis cs:-0.25, -0.25) {$O$} ;

              \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xticklabels={},yticklabels={}`.

Add that to the `axis` options. That will keep the ticks, but remove the ticklabels.